# Check if string contains words from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a `script` below that detects for words in my word filter (an array), and determines whether a `string` is clean or not.

What I have below works well when the words are used with spacing. But `ifiwritesomething` without spaces, it doesn't detect.

How can I make it such that it searches the whole string instead of words? I tried removing the `explode` function but I got some errors...

```
$string = 'goodmorningnoobs';
$array = array("idiot","noob");
if(0 == count(array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', explode(' ', $string)), $array))){

echo"clean";

} else {

echo "unclean";

}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: A word filter is so clbutty :)

Comment: Isn't that more hassle than it's worth? You'll run into a bunch of false positives

Comment: Instead of writing your own why not do a search for profanity filter as there are plenty of these plugins available http://banbuilder.com/ just to name one.

Answer (score 3):

```
$clean = true;

foreach ( $array as $word ) {
    if ( stripos($string, $word) !== false ) {
        $clean = false;
        break;
    }
}

echo $clean ? 'clean' : 'unclean';
```

Answer (score 1):

How about?

```
$hasWords = preg_match('/'. implode('|', $words) .'/', $string);

echo $hasWords ? 'unclean' : 'clean';
```

Comment: No. This will fail when elements of `$words` contain characters that have a special meaning in regular expressions.